# inserting picture in android

Tags: android

I am new to android.I want to insert a pictue (which is in c: drive) using image view control. pls give some idea related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this covers that in detail.  let us know if you have specific questions.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#drawables-from-images

Answer (score 0):

Displaying an image in an `ImageView` is quite simple. Check out this family of files from [API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html):

- [ImageView1.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ImageView1.html)
- [image_view_1.xml](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/layout/image_view_1.html)

ImageView1.java is quite simple: it just loads the xml layout file. You can change the `@drawable/...` references in `image_view_1.xml` to point to your own resources and see the effects you get with different styles of `ImageView`.

I recommend exploring the API Demos code, as it covers a large portion of the Android framework and will give you an idea about what is possible.